# How to get progression of getDocuments firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I am retrieving a lot of documents from Firestore, it can take a lot of time depending on the network connection of the user.
I would like to display a progres bar.

I didn't find any documentation on this

Here is my code :

```
final databaseReference = Firestore.instance;
databaseReference.collection("XXX").getDocuments().then((QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
      Map<String, Transac.Transaction> map = new Map<String, Transac.Transaction>();
      snapshot.documents.forEach((f)  {
//doing something
});
```

I would like to have a percentage of the data loaded. For example : 
Loading (58%)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Firestore doesn't expose any progress indicator for the documents within a query. By the time your `then` callback gets called, all documents have been loaded on the client and are present in the `QuerySnapshot`.

The usual way to deal with this is to show a "spinner" instead of a progress bar, and then hide that spinner as the first code inside your `then` callback.

Answer (score 2):

What you can do instead is just call `getDocument()` for each document individually, and track their individual completions.  You should track them in the order that you issued them, as the requests are pipelined over a single connection.  This would give you a rough sense of progress, if you're requesting lot of documents.

Comment: But this may not give the actual progress as each document size might be different. But something is better than nothing.